# Get text of edittext without losing any color

Tags: android

I am making calculator app and I have an EditText named expression.

I write some functions as colorful strings with Spannable objects. However, if I append string in EditText with a new Spannable object, I lose all colors.

My code:

```
Spannable left_of_mSpan = new SpannableString(mSpan.subSequence(0,currentCursor));
Spannable right_of_mSpan = new SpannableString(mSpan.subSequence(currentCursor,mSpan.length()));

Spannable toAdd = new SpannableStringBuilder(toAddText,0,toAddText.length());
toAdd.setSpan(color,0,toAdd.length(), 0);
expression.setText( TextUtils.concat(TextUtils.concat(left_of_mSpan,toAdd),right_of_mSpan));
```

How can I append edittext without losing colors ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  static String coloredText(String text,String color)
    {
      return String.format("<font  color='%s'>%s</font>",color,text);
    }

    String styledText =coloredText("red","#ff0000");
           styledText =styledText+coloredText("green","#00ff00");
expression.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

and this library  [html-textview](https://github.com/PrivacyApps/html-textview) support more html tags

Comment: This is working if I create both Strings in same time. What if I read edittext content and append new string to it. What should I do to make it work?